# Property 'title' not found on object of type 'id'

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode, swift

The following line is what causes the error:

```
NSLog(@"Title: %@", self.events[0].title);
```

I declared the array events earlier in the file, and I wanted to print out the event title in order to do some debugging. However, I get an error. I do not understand why I am getting this error because each event has a title property as shown in the following function.

```
@IBAction func addMedicine(sender: AnyObject) {
    objectC!.events = NSMutableArray()
    let event: DPCalendarEvent = DPCalendarEvent(title: nameText.text, startTime: startDatePicker.date, endTime: startDatePicker.date, colorIndex: 1)
    objectC!.events.addObject(event)
}
```

I was able to use events[0].title in the above function earlier when I included a NSLog statement in the function. Any idea what is causing the error? I was thinking that the error is that the two arrays aren't the same array, but I am not sure how to make the array accessible from both files. 
Note: The first line of code is in an Objective-C file and the second block of code is in a Swift file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not understand why I am getting this error because each event has a title property

Yes, but `self.events[0]` is *not* an event — at least, not as far as the compiler knows. Subscripting an array gives an `id`, and an `id` has no properties. And you have given the poor old compiler nothing further to go on. If this thing is a DPCalendarEvent, cast it to a DPCalendarEvent:

```
NSLog(@"Title: %@", ((DPCalendarEvent*)self.events[0]).title);
```

Alternatively, use Objective-C's new lightweight generics notation to say what `events` is an array of.